# Why can I not install the SQL server 2019

Tags: installation, sql-server-2019

Here is the image of the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGnPL.png)

P:S I chose the basic

Comment: Include text (hint: search for it _first_), not only images. Using the text appropriately will also help with a _terrible_ title like “this problem”.

Comment: Title is much improved, still missing the actual error message text..